# android - Share app via phone

Tags: android

i'm using this code to able my users to share apps via bluetooth or other networks . It works fine , the only problem I've is this ,when the app file received on the other phone ,it gets the package name as file name , it don't want to use package name as file name .

this is the code :

```
try {
                ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                sendIntent.setType("application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(getBaseContext().getApplicationInfo().publicSourceDir)));
                sendIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null));
            } catch (Exception e) {

                ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                sendIntent.setType("application/zip");
                uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(getApplicationInfo().publicSourceDir)));
                sendIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null));
            }
```

How can I use app name as file name when It sends to others phones?

Answer (score 0):

I made similier type of app long ago, You have to Copy that apk file somewhere into your sdcard and then you can rename it. Send it to anyone with any kind of name.